# Unity: Saving scene after using script to change object positions

Tags: unity, c#, editors

I have a c# script which makes some edits to object positions in the editor. It does this by reading some values from a csv file and then changing the value of `transform.position` for each gameobject. When I run the script all the objects appear where I want them to be in the editor. However, the editor doesn't seem to recognise any change and when I save and reload the scene the objects have reverted to their previous positions. Any ideas?

Code:

```
GameObject go = GameObject.Find(values[1]);
Undo.RecordObject(go,"setting at rest");
// Do transforms
float x = float.Parse(p_values[0]);
float y = float.Parse(p_values[1]);
float z = float.Parse(p_values[2]);
Vector3 p = new Vector3(x,y,z);

go.transform.position = p;
```

Aha I think I see my error, `Undo.RecordObject` want the specific object that is changing rather than the gameobject. I've edited the code to `Undo.RecordObject(go.transform,"setting at rest");` and it now seems to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see my error, `Undo.RecordObject` wants the specific object that is changing rather than the gameobject that is being modified (this wasn't that clear to me from the docs). I've edited the code to `Undo.RecordObject(go.transform,"setting at rest");` and it now seems to work

Comment: if it solves the problem, please accept your answer by clicking the tick icon.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, I had to wait some time before approving the answer